# Need to find expression and grab next 3 characters using regex

Tags: regex

Would prefer if there is a way to use a regular expression to do this.

What I need to do is take a string such as "abc123xyz" search for "abc" then grab the next 3 characters which would be "123".

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<=abc)(.{3})
```

This will capture any three characters following `abc`. `(?<=abc)` is a lookbehind expression. Note that not all the regex engines support lookbehind expressions.

Answer (score 1):

This regex would capture the three following characters after abc:

```
^abc(.{3})
```

If `abc` is not positioned in the start of the string simply remove the `^`-character which indicates start of string.